# How to convert HTML to Markdown while retaining non-markdown HTML tags?

Tags: markdown, pandoc

I'd like to be able to take an existing HTML snippet and convert it to markdown.
I've tried pandoc for this purpose:

```
pandoc test.html -o test.md
```

where test.html looked like this:

```
Hello

<!-- more -->

and some more text

<h2>some heading</h2>
```

The result was this:

```
Hello and some more text

some heading
------------
```

Thus, it not only converts tags that have a direct meaning in markdown. It also removes tags that I would like to retain as HTML (e.g., HTML comments,  `iframe` tags, and so on).

- How can I convert HTML to markdown in a way that any tags that don't have an equivalent in markdown are retained as raw HTML?
- More generally how can I have control over how the HTML to markdown conversion is done?

In particular, I'd be interested in command-line program options. For example, perhaps there are options that can be supplied to pandoc.

Comment: interesting, I have the exact reverse problem. It keeps the divs while I haven't asked for it

Answer (score 20):

After a bit more searching, I read about the `--parse-raw` option in a [thread on table parsing](https://code.google.com/p/pandoc/issues/detail?id=132).

Adding the `--parse-raw` option seemed to not strip the non-markdown equivalent HTML tags.

```
pandoc test.html -o test.md --parse-raw
```

Comment: `--parse-raw/-R` has been removed. Use `+raw_html` or `+raw_tex` extension.

Comment: @ZhuoerDong 2013, when the comment was written it was still pandoc 1.x but with pandoc 2.x you have to use the `+raw_html` or `+raw_tex` extension as suggested

Comment: That translates to `pandoc test.html -o test.md -f markdown+raw_html -t markdown`,  right? But that doesn't seem to do what the OP asked for 