# Pandoc drops "unknown" HTML elements when converting to markdown

Tags: html, markdown, pandoc

Consider the following simple HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<body>
<p>Test
  <object height="355" width="425">
    <param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/DKk9rv2hUfA&amp;rel=1">
    <param name="wmode" value="transparent">
    <embed height="355" src="http://www.youtube.com/v/DKk9rv2hUfA&amp;rel=1" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="425">
  </object>
</p>
</body>
```

I want to convert that to markdown, and for the elements that don't have markdown equivalents (`object`, etc.) to just pass them through as HTML unchanged. However, when I run it through pandoc (v1.13.1) with the following command line:

```
pandoc --from=html --to=markdown --output=C:\Temp\test.md C:\Temp\test.html
```

...the only output I get in `test.md` is:

```
Test
```

I am obviously missing some parameter, or is this even possible? I would think it is given that markdown allows semi-arbitrary HTML to be embedded inline.

**Note:** I have already seen [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16248986/how-to-convert-html-to-markdown-while-retaining-non-markdown-html-tags), but when I try `--parse-raw` it simply passes through **all** the HTML as HTML, which is not what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `--parse-raw` parameter is indeed what you're looking for. For example:

```
$ echo '<h1>foo</h1><p>bar <object>baz</object></p>' | pandoc -f html -t markdown --parse-raw
foo
===

bar <object>baz</object>
```

However, it seems to choke on the `<embed>` tag in your example, thus leaving the outer `<p>` tag in place instead of converting it to markdown. You should probably submit a bug report.